# Setting QItemSelectionModel crashes app

Tags: qt

setting QItemSelectionModel crashes my app. Anyone knows how to solve this?

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QItemSelectionModel>
#include <QStringListModel>
//#include "ui_Dialog.h"
//#include "File_List_Model.h"
class Dialog : public QDialog//, private Ui::Dialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QStringListModel* model_;
    QItemSelectionModel* sel_model_;
public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
    //void add_files();
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
//cpp
#include "Dialog.h"
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),model_(new QStringListModel(this))
{
    setupUi(this);
    sel_model_ = (new QItemSelectionModel(model_,this));//THIS LINE CRASHES MY APP
    listView->setModel(model_);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a full rebuild?

I just tried your code out in a test app, and it worked perfectly. Obviously I had to alter

```
//#include "ui_Dialog.h"
//#include "File_List_Model.h"
class Dialog : public QDialog//, private Ui::Dialog
```

into

```
#include "ui_Dialog.h"
//#include "File_List_Model.h"
class Dialog : public QDialog, private Ui::Dialog
```

and create a .ui file of a QDialog with a QListView called "listView" in order to make it compile.

Comment: thanks very much. After rebuilding it works. Weird... Thanks again.

Comment: will do it (and was going to anyway) with pleasure